# EF Core 7 one-to-one relation, two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm struggling with a problem of 2 foreign keys from the same table:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? HomeAddressId { get; set; }
    public int? WorkAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my fluent configuration:

```cs
...
builder.Entity<Person>()
       .HasOne(p => p.HomeAddress)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey<Person>(pl => pl.HomeAddressId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       .IsRequired(false);

builder.Entity<Person>()
       .HasOne(p => p.WorkAddress)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey<Person>(pl => pl.WorkAddressId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       .IsRequired(false);

builder.Entity<Address>()
       .HasOne(p => p.Person)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey<Address>(pl => pl.PersonId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       .IsRequired(false);
```

Adding data works fine, but when I'm deleting for example `WorkAddress` from `Person` entity, it set in database null on `WorkAddressId` column, but it does not delete `Address` from database (State == Unchanged).

Question: how to change code to not only set null on work or home address, but also delete `Address` row from database?

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you used `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` So related [addresses won't be deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-7.0).

You might want to change it to `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`, But it won't works too, because it throws you into `multiple cascade path`.

The reason might be tricky. Theoretically you are able to have one address to be used as `WorkAddress` and `HomeAddress` same time.

e.g.

```
person1.HomeAddressId = 1;
person1.WorkAddressId = 1;
```

When you try to delete this `Person` sql tries to delete this `Person`, next it tries to delete `Address with id = 1` for `HomeAddress` then it tries to delete the same address. It says i got an exception: known as `multiple cascade path`.

So, I suggest you turn it to a One-to-Many relation. Where your `Person` is able to have multiple records of `Addresse`s. you can encapsulate access to this collection to prevent from unwanted situations. you can add an `Enum` into the `Address` class to limit the number of `Person`s `Addresses`:

```
enum AddressType
{
   Home,
   Work
}
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one).